# How to make attacks deal ability damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

What ways are there to make attacks deal ability damage? For example [*calcific touch*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/calcificTouch.html) grants a touch attack that deals dexterity damage.

> ... Once per round, you may deliver a touch attack that inflicts 1d4 points of Dexterity damage and slows the target (as the spell) for 1 round. A successful Fortitude save negates the slow effect but not the ability damage. A target reduced to 0 Dexterity is petrified permanently. Break enchantment, restoration, or stone to flesh can reverse the effects of calcific touch.

Abilities that grant attacks, like *calcific touch*'s touch attack, can be modified by other abilities that modify attacks, like the Investigator's [Studied Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator#TOC-Studied-Combat-Ex-). The classic combination is *calcific touch* and [sneak attack](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/rogue.html) to quickly petrify flat-footed foes. What other abilities deal ability damage that would be increased by bonuses to attack damage rolls?

I am not interested in abilities like [disemboweling tusks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/disemboweling-tusks) that add additional ability damage to attacks, nor in those like [*poison*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/poison.html#poison) which indirectly cause ability damage. I'm interested only in those where the attack itself does ability damage.

Comment: We don't just make lists of stuff here, we focus on solving practical problems people are facing in their games. What are you trying to accomplish with this character?

Comment: @Harmelyo That *damage* isn't *ability damage* and neither are *extra damage dice* (all three of which use different rules) means this [FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nef) is unsatisfying. Paizo has, I think, not clarified if *extra damage dice* can, for example, gain an energy type or deal ability damage (this despite the presence of such a rule in *D&D 3.5*). Cirdec, if your GM says this is a go, you should mention that in your question to avoid question derailment.

Answer (score 0):

The spell [*shadow projection*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shadow-projection) gives you an incorporeal touch attack that deals 1d6 strength damage.